# A cell on 'this' sheet has a cell address of a cell on 'that' sheet. I'm trying to change the contents of the cell on 'that' sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have stopped using relative addressing and stopped using [  ] in lieu of Range.  The code that functions (but not correctly)  is below

```
Dim rStat, cLoan As Integer
Dim tabname, xFrom As String
Sheets("Status").Select

[a1].FormulaR1C1 = "=Now()"

Sheets("Status").Select

cLoan = 0
Do While Cells(2, 2 + 3 * cLoan) <> Empty
    rStat = 4
    tabname = Sheets("Status").Cells(2, 2 + 3 * cLoan)
    While Cells(rStat, 1 + 3 * cLoan) <> Empty
        If (Sheets("Status").Cells(rStat, 3 * cLoan + 2) = Empty) _
        Or (Sheets("Status").Cells(rStat, 3 * cLoan + 3) = Empty) Then


Sheets(tabname).Range(Sheets("Status").Range(Sheets("Status").Cells(rStat, 1 
+ 3 * cLoan).Value)) = [a1]

Sheets(tabname).Range(Sheets("Status").Range(Sheets("Status").Cells(rStat, 1 
+ 3 * cLoan)).Value).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        End If
        rStat = rStat + 1
    Wend
    cLoan = cLoan + 1
Loop
```

In the first iteration the test for a blank cell fails so the subject code is skipped.  Test passes the 2nd iteration so rStat is 5.  cStat still zero.

The data structure on "Status" sheet [worth 1000 words] is

```
'   A   B   C                     P
'4  P3  aa  bb                    P3
'5  P4  cc
'6  P5      dd
```

The test detects that C5 is blank, so the task is to place the date [A1] in P4 [the contents of A5] of the tabname sheet.  ie tabname.Range("P4") = date, where P4 comes from A5.

The code places the date at P3 instead P4.

I have determined that the code is using the P4 address on the Status sheet [notice that data P3 is stored at cell P4] and uses that content at that address, P3, as the destination on the tabname sheet.  That is, tabname.Range("P3") = date.

I have not determined how or why it is doing that.

Removing the ".value" from the first of the 2 ['store' and 'format'] lines does not change the destination or its content.  Still tabname.Range("P3") = date.

I need to say tabname.Range("content of Status.Range("A5")) = date

If I take out the first "Sheets("Status").",

```
Sheets(tabname).Range(Range(Sheets("Status").Cells(rStat, 1 + 3 * 
cLoan)).value) = [a1]
```

there was nothing [a blank?] stored tabname.P3 - twice. tabname.P3 is selected but empty after the macro finishes.  The 3rd time I ran this same code, I got a compiler error: With the 2nd 'Range' highlighted, " Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

I removed the ".value" and ran again.  No compiler error, but tabname.O3 is highlighted and P3 and P4 still have bogus values I put there to see if they were ignored or had blanks stored.  They were both ignored - still my bogus values.

I put bogus data in tabname.O3 to see if it was  blanked or ignored/merely highlighted and got the compiler error again.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My current code is working perfectly.
The Status sheet is wider than 26 columns so I have to calculate column references [colLetter()]

```
    rStat = 4
    tabname = Sheets("Status").Cells(2, 2 + 3 * cLoan)
    While Cells(rStat, 1 + 3 * cLoan) <> Empty
        A_Stat = colLetter(1 + 3 * cLoan) & CStr(rStat)
```

The data store is correct, and the next line, the formatting of that date, works, too.  I was expecting more formatting than I was doing.

```
Sheets(tabname).Range(Sheets("Status").Range(A_Stat)).Value = [a1]

Sheets(tabname).Range(Sheets("Status").Range(A_Stat)).NumberFormat = 
"m/d/yyyy"
```

When everything is resolved, how do I quit/leave this post?  Just quit posting?  The instructions say "Don't say Thank you".

Comment: I've read through this post a couple of times and I can't make any sense of it... please try to re-organize it, and indent your code with 4 spaces so that it appears like `this`.

Comment: I want to put a date in a cell on 'that' sheet.  The location of the cell is on another sheet, 'this' sheet.  That location is A5.  In A5 is P4.  P4 on 'that' sheet is where I want to put a date.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Dim thisSheet As WorkSheet
Dim thatSheet As WorkSheet

Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("this")
Set thatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("that")

thatSheet.Range(thisSheet.Range("A5").Value) = Date
```

If A5 on sheet "this" contains the value "P4" then this code would populate the date in P4 on sheet "that"

Comment: I can't navigate your site.  No place to 'edit' so I'll 'answer': Thank you @Tim Williams for the concept of '.value'.  I think you need to move your trailing ')' to the left of the '.'.  That's what I did:    Nope - can't insert code here (or anywhere else) so I guess the words will have to do.    
 
 
 
 Sheets(tabname).Range(Sheets("Status").Range(xFrom)).Value = [a1]

Comment: You should be able to edit your question if you have something to add.

Comment: My trailing `)` is fine, though I did omit the default/optional `.Value` just after that.